# Access to the $data variable from buttons in cgridview

Tags: php, yii, cbuttoncolumn

Is the any way, to access model located in `$data` variable from CButtonColumn?
Below code is not working.

```
array(
'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
'template' => '{test}',
    'buttons' => array(
        'test' => array(
            'label' => 'Select',
            'click' => 'js:function() { <b>alert($data->_id);</b> return false;}',
        ),
    ),
),
```

Comment: So you are outputting the PHP $data->id variable into the onClick JS? I'm not sure that will work. The $data variable is only only available when the 'click' string is eval()'d by Yii, and I think the js: perfix stops it from being eval()'d and just outputs it as a string? Hmmm

Comment: Have you got solved this? otherwise look at my answer.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to access visible attributes from jquery:

```
'click'=>'js:function(){alert("first element in cgridview is"+$(this).parent().parent().children(":nth-child(1)").text());}'
```

Answer (score 5):

The only field where **`$data`** is allowed in CButtonColumn class is  **`url`**, **`imageUrl`** and **`visible`**. To pass id to the javascript click event you may place such id in the url and grab it from the DOM. This is very rude hack but easy implementation.

```
array(
    'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
    'template' => '{test}',
    'buttons' => array(
        'test' => array(
            'label' => 'Select',
             /* set id */
            'url' => $data->id, 
             /* retrieve id from this DOM element (jQuery) */
            'click' => 'function() { alert( $(this).attr("href"); return false;}',
        ),
    ),
),
```

If you are looking for a more clear coding you could work in CDataColumn class

Answer (score 1):

It looks like _id is a private variable (according to Yii's coding "standards"). You can not access private variables (and methods) outside of an object. Create a getter-method like this in your model:

```
public function getId() {
  return $this->_id;
}
```

and then change your code to:

```
array(
    'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
    'template' => '{test}',
        'buttons' => array(
            'test' => array(
                'label' => 'Select',
                'click' => 'js:function() { alert($data->id); return false;}',
            ),
        ),
),
```

Comment: Yes, but there is still main problem: Undefined variable: data. If I reffering to $data in raw column type - it work.

Comment: It's interesting, there is access in additional field 'url'. Bug?

Comment: Uhm sry... got it wrong yesterday. Try the code above again (remove "'." from $data->id)

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize the CButtonColumn class. Have a look this post:

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/714/yii-1-1-cgridview-use-special-variable-data-in-the-options-of-a-button-i-e-evaluate-options-attribute/

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by custom function, as we can derived a $data variable inside it so that we can utilize better php as well as yii itself.

Try like this :

```
'test' => array(
          'label' => 'Select',
          'click' => function($data) {
            $id = $data->id;
            return "js:function() { alert($id); return false;}";
           },
     ),
```

Comment: As *StackOverflow* intends to be a site, where you can not only ask questions, to get them answered, but also to find already answered questions. While this might answer the question, further readers might benefit even more, if you'd include some explaination to it.